# Who made tomorrow and one out yesterday?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[In the lyrics to Money Never Build a Mountain](https://www.jah-lyrics.com/song/ronnie-davis-money-never-build-a-mountain) by Ronnie Davis, which is an old Reggae song about God the Creator, there is the line

> Who makes tomorrow and one out yesterday?

I couldn't quite parse that line. In general, the rest of that page is carefully transcribed so I don't think it's a typo or anything like that. But on the other hand I couldn't find an entry in wiktionary for "one out", or a fitting entry for "one".

So what can "one out yesterday" mean?

Comment: I checked out "make something/someone out", but didn't find anything solid.

Comment: From listening to the song, to me it sounds like "bore" or "born our yesterday", ie "gave birth to our yesterday".

Comment: Despite my answer below, I think 'bore our yesterday' is a very plausible answer as well, since it fits well with the first part of the phrase.  Unfortunately I think now that this may less a problem of understanding the MEANING of the song, and more that it's hard for even a native English speaker to understand exactly what the words are at that part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a transcription error, although not a typo.  The phrase makes sense if you spell it "won out"-- which sounds exactly the same when spoken, or in this case, sung.

"Win out" is an idiom that roughly means "achieve victory (over something or someone)".
From [The Free Dictionary Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/won+out):

> **win out**
>
> To defeat someone or something; to prevail.
>
> *We had a vote, and this is the yearbook cover that won out.*

Comment: But can "win out" be transitive? Or do you interpret "yesterday" as an adverb?

Comment: I think it is an adverb here, and used in the sense of "the general past".  Although yesterday as an adverb it is usually used for either the literal day before today or more figuratively the recent past, this isn't always the case.  Since this appears to be a Christian song, I will relate it to The Bible as an example-- Hebrew 13:8, "Jesus Christ is the same yesterday, today and forever".

Comment: Having read the lyrics, I don't think this can be the correct answer.

Comment: @RonJohn I think in retrospect that is probably true.  I looked at several difference sources for lyrics and none of them had transcribed the lyrics of that line in a way that makes any sense to me.  Most of them say "Who makes tomorrow and wanna yesterday".  I can't even speculate on what that means.